# post request returns ok but no data and function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok, I've been putting together a website for the las couple of weeks.

I got everything working before moving on to next phase. Made a lot of changes but none to the functions that I'm talking about.

basically I have a code:

```
var grabbedItems = [];

function grab(){
$.post(questions.php, {"grab":"grab"}, function(data){
    grabbedItems = data;
    console.log(grabbeditems);
}, "json");
}
```

The function gets called on page load. The problem is that network tab says 200 ok for questions.php, but console.log() doesn't even log anything. I can't think what i've done wrong. i haven't even changed the page that the function is on. What could be the problem, apache says no errors network says 200 ok. But functions are not working. I don't think there is anything wrong with my JQuery file, that returns 200 ok aswell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well as first step, you need to check for more details in the request, you can check the response (like in Chrome Dev Tools), if it's empty, means the Server is not sending any data, then you need to check your back-end.

Comment: are you calling function like grab() in your script

Comment: Make sure that in Network tab (Chrome Dev Tools) your response is not empty.

Comment: i did look, but wasn't sure what to look for. Looking now there is no responce.

Comment: for timing in chrome the connection doesn't get passed stalled, why would it return 200 ok but not be connecting.

Comment: Does the console.log line actually run? Add an error handler. My guess is if it is not running, you have invalid JSON.

Comment: how do I add an error handler, because everything on the server says ok

Comment: nothing is working, I added try{console.log(questions)}catch(err){console.log(err.message);} to it and I get nothing. How could i have invalid JSON when it worked fine before.

Comment: It's something else. I've got input forms going to php files on the same site and they are not working at all. Browser refreshes, request doesn't get sent.

Comment: Tip: put questions.php in address bar and look.

Comment: I think it is invalid JSON, as the one thing i did was add two items to a database. The php reads the database and JSON encodes an array. For some reason if I remove the items I put into the database. everything works. So it's something to do with the information in my database. Is it possible that the information is too long for JSON. One row of the database returns. 2 or 3 does not. I can't think of anything different about the other 2 rows. But for somereason they don't get returned to the function.

Comment: ok, narrowed it down further. 2 of the 3 database entries work, the other does not. I can't see any difference though. I'm checking datatypes of the mysql database. But no problems.

Comment: make sure you add quotes `'questions.php'` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the data in one of the mysql fields. I used a £ sign. for some reason the JSOn didn't like it. Maybe I should look into the coding of the database entries.